# geocomplete map display issue inside Jquery tab

Tags: jquery, google-maps, tabs

I have geocomplete inside a [Jquery tab](http://docs.zozoui.com/tabs/#options), the map drawing does not show up unless I invoke a change in the page size, changing the window size manually or dragging the console window to left or right!!

This is how I initialize:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        $("#autocomplete").geocomplete({
            map: "#map-1",
            details: "form",
            types: ["geocode", "establishment"],
            mapOptions: {
                //styles: mapStyles
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I tried using this on tab select but did not work, any idea why is this happening ?

```
var map = $("#map-1")
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

HTML markup

```js
$("#autocomplete").geocomplete({
  map: "#map-1",
  details: "form",
  types: ["geocode", "establishment"],

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/geocomplete/1.7.0/jquery.geocomplete.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/geocomplete/1.7.0/jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>

<div id="frmMaintab">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Patient Info<span>Identifcation Information</span></a></li>
    <li><a>Personal Info<span>Demographics</span></a></li>

  </ul>
  <div>

    <div>
      content of tab 1
    </div>

    <div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                                                        </span>
        <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Contact Address" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <section class="panel">
            <div class="panel-body">

              <div class="map-container">
                <div class="map-area" id="map-1">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js??key=AIzaSyCTUe4qO5LRKfzTErUSWSbnTCqJ1e-ODqc&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: Add more code, there is no reference to jquery tab and you're also not providing enough to replicate your problem. Adding some HTML wouldn't hurt too. The usual guideline is to give a small example on how to reproduce the bug.

Comment: I m adding the HTML right now

Comment: @Loïc Faure-Lacroix I have two problems, I can't find a cdn lib for the tabs, I included the doc for it in the description and I am really having hard time with google API key for the geomaps